# Is there a difference in energy walking with and against Earth's rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, momentum

If the amount of energy required to accelerate an object is dependent on an object's speed, and the earth is spinning, shouldn't take more energy to walk with the earth's rotation rather than against it?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you walk with the earth the earth also gets accelerated in the opposite direction (the same principle as you have it with the [recoil of a gun](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1051#p1051)), so the total momentum vector and the total energy is conserved in all frames.